# Xcode 14 project failed to archive: Multiple undefined symbols

Tags: xcode, react-native

On Xcode, my project is failing to archive with this errors:

Undefined symbol: _$s11SubSequenceSlTl

Undefined symbol: _$s16FloatLiteralTypes013ExpressibleByaB0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s17StringLiteralTypes013ExpressibleByaB0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s18IntegerLiteralTypes013ExpressibleByaB0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s19ArrayLiteralElements013ExpressibleByaB0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s19StringInterpolations013ExpressibleByaB0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s24UnicodeScalarLiteralTypes013ExpressibleByabC0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s34ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralTypes013ExpressibleByabcD0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s3Keys30ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteralPTl

Undefined symbol: _$s3Keys30KeyedDecodingContainerProtocolPTl

Undefined symbol: _$s5IndexSlTl

Undefined symbol: _$s5Values30ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteralPTl

Undefined symbol: _$s6Darwin10TIOCGWINSZSuvg

Undefined symbol: _$s6Darwin4openys5Int32VSPys4Int8VG_ADs6UInt16VtF

Undefined symbol: _$s6Darwin4openys5Int32VSPys4Int8VG_ADtF

Undefined symbol: _$s6Darwin5errnos5Int32Vvg

Undefined symbol: _$s6Darwin5errnos5Int32Vvs

Undefined symbol: _$s6Darwin5ioctlys5Int32VAD_SuSvtF

Undefined symbol: _$s6Darwin6stderrSpySo7__sFILEVGvg

Undefined symbol: _$s6StrideSxTl

Undefined symbol: _$s6XCTest7XCTFail_4file4lineySS_s12StaticStringVSutF

Undefined symbol: _$s6XCTest8XCTIssueV19_bridgeToObjectiveCSoABCyF

Undefined symbol: _$s6XCTest8XCTIssueV4type18compactDescription08detailedE017sourceCodeContext15associatedError11attachmentsACSo0B4TypeV_S2SSgSo09XCTSourcehI0Cs0K0_pSgSaySo13XCTAttachmentCGtcfC

Undefined symbol: _$s6XCTest8XCTIssueVMa

Undefined symbol: _$s7ElementSTTl

Undefined symbol: _$s7ElementStTl

Undefined symbol: _$s7Elements10SetAlgebraPTl

Undefined symbol: _$s7IndicesSlTl

Undefined symbol: _$s8AllCasess12CaseIterablePTl

Undefined symbol: _$s8Durations15InstantProtocolPTl

Undefined symbol: _$s8Elementss20LazySequenceProtocolPTl

Undefined symbol: _$s8IteratorSTTl

Undefined symbol: _$s8RawValueSYTl

Undefined symbol: _$s9MagnitudeSjTl

Undefined symbol: _$sBbWV

Undefined symbol: _$sBi16_WV

Undefined symbol: _$sBi32_WV

Undefined symbol: _$sBi64_WV

Undefined symbol: _$sBi8_WV

Undefined symbol: _$sBoWV

Undefined symbol: _$sBpWV

Undefined symbol: _$sS2Dyxq_GycfC

Undefined symbol: _$sS2SycfC

Undefined symbol: _$sS2ayxGycfC

Undefined symbol: _$sS

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Alredy tried "pod deintegrate > pod install > pod update"
the app builds fine on emulator, this only happens on archive.

-I tried to add missing packages like swift packages that come in xcode by default and XCtest.

-I tried to delete the arm64 architecture by adding in the podfile: config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"

-Tried to exclude arm64 architecture by adding this in "excluded architecture" in xcode's build settings.

-Updated cocoapoads and project pods to the newest version.

-Updated ruby to the newest version.